# C++ gives Error on inclusion of a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I am new to C++, I was reading about constructors and I made a program.
Below is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Demo{
    public:
        int a;
        Demo(int x,int y){
            cout<<"I am default constructor";
        }
        Demo(Demo &c){
            cout<<"I am copy Constructor";
        }
};
int main(){
    Demo c2=Demo(5,7);
    Demo c3=c2;
    cout<<"The value is: "<<c2.a;
}
```

This code was working fine until I added the copy constructor in class and the second line in the main function. As soon as I added these lines, It shows error in the first line of main function.
The error says:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Demo::Demo(Demo)'
note: candidates are:
note: Demo::Demo(Demo&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Demo' to 'Demo&'
note: Demo:Demo(int,int)
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

My first question is, I am passing two arguments in the constructor then Why the compiler is not able to distinguish and call the correct constructor?

My second question is, If I change the first line of main to be like this:
 `Demo c2(5,7);` 
then It works fine. Why is this so?
Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide

Comment: `Demo(Demo &c)` --> `Demo(const Demo &c)`. A temporary r-value object can't be referenced by a non const reference variable.

Answer (score 1):

> My first question is, I am passing two arguments in the constructor then Why the compiler is not able to distinguish and call the correct constructor?

The compiler *is* calling the `Demo(int x,int y)` constructor on the right hand side of the line in main,

```
Demo c2 = Demo(5,7);
        ^ ^
        | |
        | +------- call Demo(int x,int y) to construct an r-value Demo object
        |
        +--------- call Demo(Demo&) copy constructor to construct a Demo object
```

However, r-values cannot be bound to non-const references. So this line is (attempting to) construct two `Demo` objects. Only one is succeeding.

r-values can be bound to `const` references, so the solution is to add `const`:

```
Demo(const Demo &c)
```

---

> My second question is, If I change the first line of main to be like this:
>   `Demo c2(5,7);`
>   then It works fine. Why is this so?

In this case, the appropriate constructor is called. Again, adding `const` to your copy constructor will clear this up.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir, for answering. I think my concept is not clear regarding this. What I knew about this was: The copy constructor is only called when we pass an object in the constructor as I did in second line of main function. I got a fuzzy idea of what's happening here and why the error. But even then these terms like `r-value object` and `const reference variable` not making much sense to me. Can u please suggest me some source from where I can understand these things in depth

Comment: Initializing an object like `T a = b;` will also call the copy constructor, if `b` is of type `T`. Do you have a good C++ book? We have a list.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I don't have a book, I am following one youtube channel playlist Mysirg.com

Comment: I recommend a book. That and answering questions on Stack overflow haha.

Comment: Okay, I'll follow a book

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Demo c2=Demo(5,7);
```

is known as [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). Copy initialization requires calling the copy constructor, which is why you got errors after you added your explicit copy constructor. From [cppreference's copy constructor page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

> The copy constructor is called whenever an object is initialized (by direct-initialization or **copy-initialization**) from another object of the same type (unless overload resolution selects a better match or the call is elided), which includes...

Since your copy constructor is

```
Demo(Demo &c)
```

this causes a problem as it attempts to bind a non-const [lvalue to an rvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). To resolve this, and the second error, modify your copy constructor to take a const reference

```
Demo(const Demo &c)
```

> My second question is, If I change the first line of main to be like this:
>   Demo c2(5,7);
>   then It works fine. Why is this so?

In this case, the copy constructor is no longer called. Instead, your overloaded constructor

```
Demo(int x,int y)
```

is being called directly, thus the copy constructor is never invoked in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving such an explanatory answer with references as well. Thank you, sir.